# Some Spring WebSocket Sessions never disconnect

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a websocket solution for duplex communication between mobile apps and a java backend system. I am using Spring WebSockets, with STOMP. I have implemented a ping-pong solution to keep websockets open longer than 30 seconds because I need longer sessions than that. Sometimes I get these errors in the logs, which seem to come from [checkSession() in Spring's SubProtocolWebSocketHandler](http://www.massapi.com/source/github/40/71/407140336/spring-websocket/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/socket/messaging/SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java.html).

server.log: 07:38:41,090 ERROR [org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler] (ajp-http-executor-threads - 14526905) No messages received after 60205 ms. Closing StandardWebSocketSession[id=214a10, uri=/base/api/websocket].

They are not very frequent, but happens every day and the time of 60 seconds seem appropriate since it's hardcoded into the Spring class mentioned above. But then after running the application for a while I start getting large amounts of these really long-lived 'timeouts':

server.log: 00:09:25,961 ERROR [org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler] (ajp-http-executor-threads - 14199679) No messages received after 208049286 ms. Closing StandardWebSocketSession[id=11a9d9, uri=/base/api/websocket].

And at about this time the application starts experiencing problems.

I've been trying to search for this behavior but havn't found it anywhere on the web. Has anyone seen this problem before, know a solution, or can explain it to me?

Answer (score 2):

We found some things:

1. We have added our own ping/pong functionality on STOMP level that runs every 30 seconds.
2. The mobile client had a bug that caused them to keep replying to the pings even when going into screensaving mode. This meant that the websocket was never closed or timed out.
3. On each pong message that the server received the Spring check found that no 'real' messages had been received for a very long time and triggered the log to be written. It then tries to close the websocket with this code:

   session.close(CloseStatus.SESSION_NOT_RELIABLE);

but I suspect this doesn't close the session correctly. And even if it did, the mobile clients would try to reconnect. So when 30 more seconds have passed another pong message is sent to the server causing yet another one of these logs to be written. And so on forever...

The solution was to write some server-side code to close old websockets based on [this project](https://github.com/isaranchuk/spring-websocket-disconnect) and also to fix the bug in the mobile clients that made them respond to ping/pong even when being in screensaver mode.

Oh, one thing that might be good for other people to know is that clients should never be trusted and we saw that they could sometimes send multiple request for websockets within one millisecond, so make sure to handle these 'duplicate requests' some way!

Comment: What version of Spring are you using and was this reported on Jira?

Comment: We are using 4.1.4.RELEASE if I'm not mistaken, and no, it has not been reported on Jira as I am still not sure if the problem is on our side or on Spring side.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same problem.

net stat on Linux output shows tcp connections and status as below:

```
  1 LISTEN
 13 ESTABLISHED
 67 CLOSE_WAIT
```

67 TCP connections are waiting to be closed but these are never getting closed.